# kendo ui multiselect searchable dropdown for searching quick data coming from service

Tags: angularjs, search, kendo-ui, multi-select

When I am clicking on searchable drop-down. I am passing value to back-end service when user start typing, some time back-end service take time and I am able to get value. but if service sending response quickly then result is not matching.it show empty drop-down .ex. when i click 1 it show result as per image. when i click its again working but when i click fast 136 its showing none.
[screen shot][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDaJg.png

Comment: I would think this is expected behavior. Server request take time, and will always differ. Instead of doing this on every key stroke, try sending on every 3rd.  Also, if possible, cache the data that is being retrieved. Or maybe even keep the data client side, and prevent the serve calls all together.

Comment: i tried same, but not working